# Increment build number in bash

Tags: bash, unix, scripting

I am trying to increment a build number by 1 using command line.

Here is the content of my test file:

```
SOME_DUMMY_VALUE = -1;
CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION = 4;
SOME_SECOND_DUMMY_VALUE = -1;
CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION = 4;
```

The result I want to obtain is the following:

```
SOME_DUMMY_VALUE = -1;
CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION = 5;
SOME_SECOND_DUMMY_VALUE = -1;
CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION = 5;
```

I am trying to use something like:

```
sed -i -E "s/CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION = (\d+);/CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION = \1~;/" test.txt
```

I am not experienced in bash scripting and I don't know how I can increment the number by one. (I am using MacOS but the sed command is almost the same as on Linux)

Comment: Why does `CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION` appear in the input twice?

Comment: It is the format of my input file, it can appear multiple times.

Comment: First thing, get the build numbers out of  your files.  Use a build system that generates build numbers in a reasonable way.  Otherwise, use `awk` to increment[

Answer (score 2):

With `.../e` you can instruct `sed` to execute the replacement string.

```
sed -i -E 's/(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION = )([0-9]+)/echo "\1$((\2+1))"/e' test.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

`sed` doesn't do arithmetic. `awk`, however, does. One possibility:

```
awk '/CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION/ { $3=$3+1";"}; 1' test.txt > tmp && mv tmp test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to change the question slightly :) so that the build number has its own file, Mitch Frazier in Linux journal https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/add-auto-incrementing-build-number-your-build-process offers this bash two liner:

```
if ! test -f build-number.txt; then echo 0 > build-number.txt; fi
echo $(($(cat build-number.txt) + 1)) > build-number.txt
```

I would like this to be verbose and start at 1, here's my version:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=build-number.txt
echo "Using file $file"
if ! [ -f $file ] ; then
    echo 1 > $file
else
    echo "old build number $(cat $file)"
    echo $(($(cat $file) + 1)) > $file
fi
new=$(cat $file)
echo "new build number $new"
```